# how on complete apply filter to a datatable primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I need the FilterValue "Albacete" to be applied to the datatable before loading the page. 
I tried with an onload commandbutton but this does not work.
Any ideas?

```
<p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{delegacionesController.items}" var="item" widgetVar="itemtable"
                         emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria"
                         filteredValue="#{delegacionesController.filteredDelegaciones}"
                         selectionMode="single" selection="#{delegacionesController.selected}"

                         rowKey="#{item.delegacion}"
                         rows="100">

    <p:commandButton oncomplete="preFilter"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('itemtable').filter()" 
                style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
    <p:column id="preFilter" filterBy="#{item.delegacion}"  rendered="false" filterValue="Albacete">
    </p:column>
```

Comment: You need the filter applied, but do you also need to be able to remove it then from the ui? Or is it a kind of 'search-result'?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem as follows

```
    <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{delegacionesController.items}" var="item" widgetVar="itemtable"
                             emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria"
                             filteredValue="#{delegacionesController.filteredDelegaciones}"
                             selectionMode="single" selection="#{delegacionesController.selected}"

                             rowKey="#{item.delegacion}"
                             rows="100"
                             >
                    >
                    <p:commandButton oncomplete="preFilter"/>
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputPanel>
                            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('itemtable').filter()" style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </f:facet>

<script  type="text/javascript" target="body">
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery('input[id*="itemtable"]').val('Albacete');
                    PF('dataWidget').filter();
                });
            </script> 
</p:datatable>
```

if it is going to use a diffent process

```
<p:column id="preFilter" filterBy="#{item.delegacion}"  rendered="false" filterValue="Albacete">
                </p:column>
```

you need to solve as follows

```
<script  type="text/javascript" target="body">
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery('input[id*="preFilter"]').val('Albacete');
                    PF('dataWidget').filter();
                });
            </script>
```